# .Net Standard vs PCL Xamarin Project

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I want to learn Xamarin on VS 2017. I can't find the same project as I see in most of all tutorials or guides. I have ".Net Standard" project and not Portable Class Library project. (see images).

[[image: What I need]]

[[image: what I have]]

I have installed all components of vs2017 but I can't see it.

[[image: installed components]]

Why I can't see it? Are they the same?

(edit: the xamarin official site have 3 options, so I don't think they are)

[image: xamarin site]

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/2724 PCL is dying so use .NET Standard and don't look back.

Comment: Here you can find  [What is .NET Standard](https://blog.xamarin.com/net-standard-library-support-for-xamarin/) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET Standard is the next evolution of Portable Class Libraries. Simply, they are PCLs but better. Choose a .NET Standard project and go through the tutorials as though you had used a PCL. When just starting out, you probably won't notice a difference until you start adding a lot of nuget packages.